# UPDATE.. WHERE... - can a transaction happen in between

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, transactions, innodb

If I make a SQL statement like the following

```
 UPDATE table SET a='000' WHERE b='Me!';
```

Assuming the query found a row that satisfies the condition, is it possible for another transaction to change the value of field 'b' before my update is made?

If that is the case, I'm assuming my transaction will fail when I try to commit?

Comment: Yes it will fail because your syntax is wrong. `UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...`

Comment: Okay. I'm typing on my phone because our company blocks stack overflow. I'm surprised you couldn't understand the gist of my question.

Comment: You are adding absolutely no value to StackOverflow Rafael

Comment: Please add a tag for the DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, ...) you are using. Is `b` a primary or unique key?

Comment: No it is not a key. I've added tags for MySQL on innodb

Answer (score 0):

If another transaction already updated and not committed the row that has a `b = Me!`, you'll gonna have row locked exception. If it's committed, that means b value changed, your query will not affect the row.

Second option, you have already updated the row and another query wants to update the row before you commit. In this case second transaction will get row locked error. If you already committed, other query will not affect the row.

You wont get any error message or exception when you commit. You will get when run update query if there is any error.